# Stuck with setting Room to work with RxJava: access to database may potentially lock the UI

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, android-room

So I'm trying to understand how to be reactive and how to use Room library but I'm getting some exception, which I don't know how to solve:

```
08-11 20:35:44.349 8797-8797/ru.android_school.h_h.eightapp W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onError(LambdaSubscriber.java:79)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:69)
08-11 20:35:44.350 8797-8797/ru.android_school.h_h.eightapp W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onNext(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:97)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.runAsync(FlowableObserveOn.java:400)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.run(FlowableObserveOn.java:176)
    at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
08-11 20:35:44.351 8797-8797/ru.android_school.h_h.eightapp W/System.err:     at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:204)
    at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:232)
    at ru.android_school.h_h.eightapp.note_trio.NoteDao_Impl.getBySearch(NoteDao_Impl.java:230)
    at ru.android_school.h_h.eightapp.note_list.ListActivity$1.onMenuItemActionCollapse(ListActivity.java:59)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.collapseActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:841)
    at ru.android_school.h_h.eightapp.note_list.ListActivity$4.accept(ListActivity.java:111)
    at ru.android_school.h_h.eightapp.note_list.ListActivity$4.accept(ListActivity.java:107)
    at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:65)
    ... 11 more
```

caused in onCreate() of MainActivity by:

```
db.noteDao()
            .getAllLive()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Note>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Note> notes) throws Exception {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                    listOfNotes.clear();
                    listOfNotes.addAll(notes);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (listOfNotes.size() != 0) {
                        findViewById(R.id.emptyListReplacer).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        findViewById(R.id.emptyListReplacer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

where db is obviously a database and noteDao implementing a Dao interface. I'm new to reactive programming and multithreading and I have no idea how to solve it. Please help?

**UPD**: Using of .allowMainThreadQueries() in databaseBuilder solves the problem, but, as i understand, this is wrong way to fixing a problem.

Comment: Could you post the entire Java stack trace?

Comment: Could you also post the full `subscribe(new Consumer<List<Note>>() {...})`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Updated text for you, would be glad if it helps you solve my problem

Comment: Your exception is not coming from that code. Your exception is coming from `getBySearch()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh thank you man, I'm blind. This fragment of code do not contains errors at all. What a shame...

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be :

```
db.noteDao()
            .getAllLive()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // <-- subscribe to upstream task on io
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // <-- observe downstream result back on UI
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Note>>() {...});
```

If you access your db currently like you did in your post in more places, then use this threading approach if you want to perform db actions on `io` and all your consumers in the subscribe to be on the UI thread.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn'thelp, i'm getting the same exception.

Comment: @Arantier because your updated stacktrace doesn't match your code provided --> where is this called : `noteDoa().getBySearch` <--- thats the method causing your stacktrace error.

Comment: @Arantier edited answer - you should use this approach in all interactions with your `Dao` class.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions were not caused by this piece of code. The problem was in the methods insert() and getBySearch(), not specified by me in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the supposed function `.getAllLive()` is the simplest possible, only access to database, the thread check performs in the main thread (like in all the cases if you construct the pipeline in the main thread), in my auto generated code by room is:

```
@Override
public Completable markAsOutOfRoom(final int idRoom) {
    final SupportSQLiteStatement _stmt = __preparedStmtOfMarkAsOutOfRoom.acquire();
    int _argIndex = 1;
    _stmt.bindLong(_argIndex, idRoom);
    return Completable.fromCallable(new Callable<Void>() { ... } );
}
```

But, the thread check is perform on the first line `__preparedStmtOfMarkAsOutOfRoom.acquire();` and the room throws that exception. Well, in almost all cases this is not a problem, this acquire not throw the exception:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`
But it can happen to throw this exception, is possible there may be an error in your code, but in my case the code is the simplest possible, there can be no mistake (at least in my code). It may be for internal reasons of android, in any case, if you have this problem, I propose a temporary solution:

```
getCompositeDisposable().add(
  Single.fromCallable(() -> 
    db.noteDao()
      .getAllLive()
  )
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe(s ->
    getCompositeDisposable.add(
      s.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(allLive -> { /* do anything with the result */ } )
    )
  )
);
```

It create a completable that perform the lazy creation of the pipeline of the desired execution.